# I as the user, am trying to add myself to local administrator group on the box

Tags: windows-7, localhost, powershell-2.0

so im working out an exercise and wanted to ask what possible avenues there were to do this (preferably through powershell v2)

I have tried the following from a batch file casually written:
C:\windows\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe "
net localgroup Administrators test1 /add -force

so that doesn't work, ill get an "access denied" and I'm not sure how to jump that authorization.

Answer (score 3):

If you're not logged on as a user that has administrator rights on the computer, you can't upgrade yourself. Only an administrator can. If there were a way for you to do it, it would completely defeat the purpose of having the controls in the first place.

Even the malware exploits that grant an "outsider" administrator-level access to your computer rely on an unknowledgeable user doing all of their routine work in an Administrator account, and then "social-engineering" the user into running the exploit with admin privileges.

Comment: so what options exist to upgrade the user account i am currently on to local admin of the box without doing some kind of lsass dump -> mimi katz